# After Game Center "Create New Account" screen, I get a Black Screen

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, game-center

I am working on an OpenGL iPhone game. When I go back from GameCenter's "Create a new account", i get a black screen.

I have also tried using GameCenter via OpenFeint. Still it gives a black screen. Can anyone tell me if I can get any kind of Notification when that GameCenter's "Create new account" screen is closed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your openGL view(EAGLView) may be on the top of nib file of rootviewcontroller, so while your app gets memory warnings, your EAGLView gets dealloc causing glview disappear from the rootviewcontroller. So remove memory warnings and also try to remove nib files which causes to dealloc EAGLView when memory warnings received. U can easily remove MainWindow.xib by putting the AppDelegate class name in main.m and remove .xib file from compiled resources in build phase.